# How to set the version number metadata on a zip file?

Tags: finder, zip, extended-attributes

I use zip files as a simple way of bundling some macOS software for distribution in our organization. I want to set the version number displayed by the Finder's *Get Info* box, similar to how a version number is shown when you use *Get Info* on an application. Example (from a regular application, not a zip file):

[image]

Currently, my zip files lack a version number:

[image]

**Is there a way to put a version number into a zip file**, so that it's shown in the Finder's *Get Info* panel?  The `zip` command itself does not appear to have a flag to control this, but perhaps there is an extended attribute or other method that could be used to achieve this?

**Edit**: it's hopefully obvious that I'm looking for a solution *other* than writing the version number into the comment field.

Comment: You can add it as a comment

Comment: What you are seeing there is defined as the `CFBundleShortVersionString` _key_ in the _application bundle's_ `Info.plist` _file_ and not an extended attribute. I just always manually add the _version number_ to the `.zip` _filename_.

Comment: @ user3439894 putting the version number into the file name is in fact what I've resorted to doing, but it's not the most robust solution. I'm hoping there's a better approach. (Maybe there isn't!)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by distribute? If apps then just have those on a file server